# Make file that compiles gcc and puts the objects in a separate folder

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to create a make file that will work accordingly

```
OBJECT_DIRECTORY := out/obj
C_SOURCE_FILES = (Path and files fetched from different make files)
CFLAGS += -mcpu=$(CPU) -mthumb -mabi=aapcs -mfloat-abi=soft 
CFLAGS += -Wall -Werror
CFLAGS += -D$(DEVICE) -std=gnu99

$(OBJECT_DIRECTORY)/%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(C_SOURCE_FILES) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

I verified that the C_SOURCE_FILES variable actually contains the c source files. This since I am able to compile using this:

```
$(OBJECT_DIRECTORY)/%.o: 
    $(CC) $(C_SOURCE_FILES) $(CFLAGS) -c
```

Problem with that is that the object files are not placed in the folder where I need them for the linking.

By the way, I am executing the make file from the Eclipse C/C++ IDE

I would be extremely happy if someone could help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(OBJECT_DIRECTORY)/%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

You don't need the `C_SOURCE_FILES` variable here.  This recipe will create out/obj/{file}.o for every file called {file}.c.

You don't show it, but the dependency list for the executable being created from the object files must explicitly call out each object file.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, I think... By creating a list of target files to be used in the compilation.

```
# Create the object file names needed for the target. Make needs these file names as target for the compilation
TEMP := $(notdir $(C_SOURCE_FILES:.c=.o))
C_OBJECT_FILES := $(addprefix $(OBJECT_DIRECTORY)/, $(TEMP:.c=.o) )
TEMP_1 := $(notdir $(ASSEMBLER_SOURCE_FILES:.s=.o))
ASSEMBLER_OBJECT_FILES := $(addprefix $(OBJECT_DIRECTORY)/,$(TEMP_1:.s=.o) )

# Tells make to compile all the files in the C_OBJECTS_VARIABLE
all: $(C_OBJECT_FILES)

# Do the compilation of the c files and place the object files in the out/obj folder
$(C_OBJECT_FILES): $(C_SOURCE_FILES)
$(CC) $(CFLAGS)  -M $< -MF "$(@:.o=.d)" -MT $@
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

# Tells make to compile all the files in the ASSEMBLER_OBJECTS_VARIABLE
all: $(ASSEMBLER_OBJECT_FILES)

# Do the compilation of the assembler files and place the object files in the out/obj folder
$(ASSEMBLER_OBJECT_FILES): $(ASSEMBLER_SOURCE_FILES)
    $(CC) $(ASMFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

This works well and consistently. Issue I have now is that the rule for linking is not executed at all...

```
## Link C and assembler objects to an .out file
$(BINARY_DIRECTORY)/$(OUTPUT_FILENAME).out: $(C_OBJECT_FILES) $(ASSEMBLER_OBJECT_FILES) $(LIBRARIES)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(BINARY_DIRECTORY)/$(OUTPUT_FILENAME).out
```

I am wondering if it has anything to do with "all:"

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution to that problem as well. I created a couple of new rules to make sure that the linking is getting executed. Now the make file works well.